# Deploying apps to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I came across this repository: https://github.com/hatnote/rcmap and saw that most files are .js files in the code. It also has main.js under the static folder.
I have very basic knowledge of node.js, so I tried deploying it in Heroku cloning the github folder.

However, it fails with the message that no Cedar app was detected.

```
!Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:stark-mesa-4834.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:stark-mesa-4834.git'
```

What am I missing? Are some additional files needed? Or this repo cannot be deployed to Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Heorku only recognizes Node.js apps via a Node Packaged Modules (NPM) `package.json` file. It looks like the app you're trying to deploy doesn't use NPM.

See:

- Getting Started with Node.js on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs#declare-dependencies-with-npm
- NPM: https://npmjs.org/